# Como converter um int em dois bytes em C/C++?

Tags: c, c++, int, byte

Eu recebo os dados de um sensor de temperatura em um microcontrolador que tem um conversor AD de 10 bits. Eu armazeno os dados em uma variável do tipo `int` (de 32 bits), e preciso enviar esses dados via comunicação serial. Para isto, preciso converter esse valor `int` para o tipo `byte`, porém como se tratam de 10 bits se eu converter para apenas um `byte` perderei informação, logo, preciso converter o `int` para dois `bytes` de forma que eu possa transmitir um byte por vez pela porta serial. Também precisarei converter esses dois `bytes` em um valor inteiro novamente.

Como converto um `int` em dois `bytes` e dois `bytes` em um `int` novamente, utilizando `C/C++`?

Comment: Tente ser um pouco mais explícito. Quando você diz int está querendo dizer 32 bits? E quando diz converter para 2 bytes é para converter para um short int de 16 bits?

Comment: Fiz algumas edições na minha pergunta. Mas o int é de 32 bits e os dois bytes são separados, pois preciso enviar byte a byte pela porta serial.

Comment: `int` nas plataformas mais modernas tem 4 bytes. E 4 bytes não cabem dentro de 2 bytes, infelizmente. Mas se você estiver falando de `short int` aí sim da pra dividí-lo em bytes separados. ;D

Comment: O conversor AD armazena a informação em 10 bits. Estou armazenando isto num int de 32, mas daria para armazenar em um short. Porém a parte mais significativa está toda zerada já que os valores vão de 0 a 1023 somente. Entretanto, não posso enviar um int, preciso enviar os dados byte a byte, então preciso dividir esse int em 2 bytes (com a parte menos significativa) onde estará os valores de 0 a 1023.

Comment: @Avelino Se você precisar fazer a operação inversa, me avisa que eu atualizo a resposta.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Algo que temos que esclarecer antes é que o tipo `int` nas plataformas modernas tem **4 bytes**. Isso é um problema porque **é impossível fazer 4 bytes caberem dentro de 2 bytes**, não é verdade?!

Por outro lado, existe a [garantia que o tipo `short int` ocupa pelo menos **2 bytes**](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) em qualquer plataforma. Essas afirmações podem ser facilmente verificadas através do `sizeof()`, que retorna a quantidade de bytes que um determinado tipo de dado ocupa:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));
printf("%d\n", sizeof(short int));
```

**Desta forma, esta reposta assume que você gostaria de separar cada byte de uma variável `short int`**.

Para realizar esta tarefa, podemos utilizar uma **[máscara de bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29)**, que envolve a aplicação de operações de [lógica binária](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_bin%C3%A1ria) (*bitwise operations*) e deslocamento de bits (*bit shift*) para extrair os 8 bits que nos interessam da variável original.

Para começar esta tarefa, declaramos e inicializamos uma variável apropriada:

```
short int num = 42345;
```

É interessante notar que o número `42345` na base decimal é representado por `1010 0101 0110 1001` no sistema de base binária. É relevante saber isso porque depois que a separação ocorrer, teremos uma variável `unsigned char` para armazenar o primeiro byte --> `0110 1001` (105), e uma outra variável `unsigned char` para armazenar o segundo byte --> `1010 0101` (165).

**Para extrair o primeiro byte de `num`:**

```
unsigned char byte1 = (num & 255);          // Ou: (num & 0xFF)
printf("%d\n\n", byte1);
```

**Para extrair o segundo byte de `num`:**

```
unsigned char byte2 = ((num >> 8) & 255);   // Ou: ((num >> 8) & 0xFF);
printf("%d\n", byte2);
```

O objetivo da resposta não é discutir como funcionam as máscaras de bits, mas demonstrar como o problema poderia ser resolvido desta maneira. Existem mais de uma centena de livros de programação e muito mais registros online que descrevem em detalhes o funcionamento de máscaras de bits.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Não há garantia nenhuma de que `short` **sempre** terá 2 bytes. Isso é verdade, no entanto, em qualquer plataforma que já ouvi falar. Outro ponto: o `& 255` é desnecessário já que a conversão para `unsigned char` já dará conta disso. Ainda assim é bom manter por legibilidade.

Comment: Olá, obrigado. Você poderia apontar uma referência que diz que `short int` não tem 16 bits na linguagem C?

Comment: Standard do C11 (N1570), seção 5.2.4.2.1 "Sizes of integer types": "The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if
preprocessing directives. [...] ***Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown***, with the same sign. [...] maximum value for an object of type `unsigned short int`
USHRT_MAX 65535"  Ou seja: o tipo `unsigned short int` deve ter **ao menos** 2 bytes. Mas pode ter mais. Não há nenhuma limitação em lugar nenhum.

Comment: Eu li a seção, obrigado. Vou ajustar a explicação na resposta :)

Answer (score 12):

Converter `valor` em 2 bytes:

```
byte[0] = valor / 256;
byte[1] = valor % 256;
```

Converter dois bytes

```
valor = byte[0] * 256 + byte[1];
```

Isto para Big Endian, se preferires Little Endian, troca os bytes

Comment: Poderia me explicar o funcionamento deste código? Está obscuro para mim.

Comment: Qual e a tua duvida do codigo? Sao as operacoes (`/`, `%`, `*`)?

Comment: Qual a mágica por trás disto? A parte matemática... Não compreendo como essas operações são responsáveis por fazer a conversão.

Comment: Digamos entao que tens o valor 1023 (`1111111111` em binario). 1023 / 256 da 3 e resto 255; ou seja vai `3` (`11`) para o primeiro byte e 255 (`11111111`) para o outro

Comment: Operações de divisão não seriam mais pesadas do que simplesmente shift? no caso ele sugere está em um microcontrolador já que usa um Conversor AD, portanto é importante ter cautela com certas escolhas.

Comment: De fato, como se está usando valores potência de 2, shifts e bitwise-ands resultariam em performance superior.

Comment: Em principio o compilador fará essas optimizações directas. Eu prefiro ver `a / 256` do que `a >> 8` ou `a % 256` do que `a & 0xff`.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode utilizar `union` para fazer esse tipo de operação.

Dessa forma:

```
union Valor
{
    uint32_t dword;

    struct
    {
        uint32_t valor;
    };

    struct
    {
        uint16_t word0;
        uint16_t word1;
    };

    struct
    {
        uint8_t byte0;
        uint8_t byte1;
        uint8_t byte2;
        uint8_t byte3;
    };
};
```

Mas, verifique se o compilador suporta isso antes. Digo isso pois tem muito compilador para microcontrolador bem limitado. As variáveis `uint32_t`, `uint16_t` e `uint8_t` podem ter outro nome dependendo do compilador (versão, plataforma e etc), mas geralmente estão definidas em `#include <stdint.h>`.

### Int para 2 bytes

Daí você usa isso assim:

```
Valor var;
var.valor = 700;

printf("Valor = %d\n", var.valor);
printf("Byte 0 = %d\n", var.byte0);
printf("Byte 1 = %d\n", var.byte1);
printf("Word 0 = %d\n", var.word0);
```

Como você quer 2 bytes, você quer o `word0` (para Big Endian).

Também pode ser:

```
uint32_t variavel_qualquer = 700;
Valor* var = (Valor*) &variavel_qualquer;
printf("Word 0 = %d\n", var->word0);
```

### 2 bytes para Int

```
Valor var;
var.valor = 0; // Para garantir que estará tudo zero.

var.byte0 = 188;
var.byte1 = 2;

printf("Resultado = %d", var.valor); // Retorna 700
```

No IdeOne: http://ideone.com/9e69z6

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples é utilizar os operadores Shift e Bit-Wise, principalmente porque o mesmo é facilmente mapeado para uma instrução *Assembly* equivalente e como estamos em um contexto de ***microcontrolador*** é fundamental que tenhamos o código mais optimizado possível.

```
int orig = 0x0403;
byte dest[4];

// para converter de inteiro para byte
dest[0] = orig         & 0xff;
dest[1] = (orig >> 8)  & 0xff; 
dest[2] = (orig >> 16)  & 0xff; 
dest[3] = (orig >> 24)  & 0xff; 

// para retornar os dois byte para um inteiro
orig = (dest[3] << 24) + (dest[2] << 16) + (dest[1] << 8) + dest[0]
```