# Em Java por que (250 >> 4) é mais otimizado que (250 / 16)?

Tags: java, desempenho, operadores, otimização, bit

Estou fazendo um curso de Java e em uma aula o professor falou que esse código:

```
int xstart = Camera.x >> 4;
int ystart = Camera.y >> 4;
```

é mais "rápido ou otimizado" que esse código:

```
int xstart = Camera.x/16;
int ystart = Camera.y/16;
```

mas ele não falou o porque e nem como isso `>>` se chama. Eu gostaria de saber o que esse operador faz como se chama e porque é mais otimizado.

Comment: Ele se chama `bitwise operator`, e serve pra manipular o dado por meio da inserção de bits à esquerda ou direita. Praticamente, se você usar um compilador mais atual, não irá dar pra sentir a diferença entre os dois.

Comment: @ThRnk Obrigado! e sabe me dizer porque isso é equivalente a uma divisão?

Comment: PS: O operador não se chama `bitwise operator`  esse  é o nome da categoria a qual pertence esse e outros operadores o nome é `STR`(Shift to Right). O operador contrário é `STL`(Shift to Left).

Comment: Como os bits são contados multiplicando por 2, `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...` o mesmo seria se contasse para trás, dividindo por 2, `32, 16, 8, 4...`. Por exemplo, temos o valor 32 e queremos dividir por 2, `32 >> 1`, repassamos o número inteiro 1 bit para a direita `100000` -> `010000` resultando em 16. Seria algo nesse estilo.

Comment: `>> 4` pode até ser que seja mais otimizado, mas é muito menos legível e intuitivo do que `/16` quando você revisitar o código.

Comment: Basicamente, se vc desloca os bits N posições para a direita, é o mesmo que dividir o número por 2^N. Lembrando que isso só é equivalente para números positivos (teste com um negativo e verá que dá diferença). E a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) chama esse operador de "*signed right shift*"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você testou? Alguém falar e ser verdade vai uma grande diferença.

Eu não vou dizer e não tenho agora um ambiente que eu possa fazer um teste adequado para mostrar se isso é realmente verdade ou não. E não vou gastar meu tempo porque eu posso afirmar que a linguagem não fala nada sobre isso.

Pode ser que alguma implementação da linguagem, talvez mesmo a mais usada por todos possa ser assim, ou pode ser que não, pelo menos nesse exemplo.

Algumas linguagens possuem filosofia de executar de forma mais rápida possível e tenderá fazer otimizações onde encontra alguma situação que o compilador ou [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) consegue. Java é uma linguagem que tende fazer isso, e eu acharia estranho se não fizesse.

A divisão é uma das operações únicas mais lentas que um processador pode fazer e tem várias formas de otimizá-la e trocá-la por outras formas. Alguns compiladores (em C/C++, Fortran, etc.) chegam inclusive fazer otimizações em números "quebrados". Os que não fazem em números quaisquer pelo menos fazem em números que são potência de 2, que é o caso de 16 (2 elevado a 4), já que o computador é todo binário.

Se fosse uma variável ali no divisor seria mais complicado porque aí ele não saberia se pode ou não fazer a otimização até o momento da execução. Em alguns casos o JITter poderia beneficiar-se disso, mas só em cenários específicos ou extremos obteria o ganho.

Então há uma grande chance disso não ser verdade. O compilador/JITter pode trabalhar por você para deixar seu código ser escrito de forma mais legível e ter a melhor performance possível ao mesmo tempo.

Se isso de fato não ocorrer, se você testou, corretamente, e percebeu que de fato a otimização não ocorre, e essa otimização é importante dentro do contexto (hoje ganhar em cima do acesso à memória é muito mais importante que reduzir ciclos de processamentos, pode ser que uma otimização aí só faça uma parte ir mais rápido para cair no congestionamento antes e ficar preso ali), se tudo indicar ser importante e a legibilidade não for tão importante então trocar o operador de divisão pelo operador de ***bit shift*** (especificamente o *shift to right*) no seu código pode dar uma ganho interessante.

De maneira alguma estou dizendo que essa micro otimização no código não deva ser feita. Seu professor pode ter medido e visto que o mais comum é que o Java, no momento, não faça essa otimização, só tenha em mente que isso pode não ser verdade em todas implementações do Java e em qualquer momento. Isso pode mudar mês que vem, pode ter mudado mês passado e ninguém notou ainda, ou pode ser até que em alguma situação mais específica a otimização ocorra.

Mais sobre o assunto já foram respondidos em outras linguagens e funciona igual, por isso não vou explicar de novo:

- [Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101)
- [Qual a função dos operadores <<, >> e >>> no Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7889/101)
- [Como funcionam os operadores de bit?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91049/101)
- [Dúvida em como utilizar o Shift em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192882/101)
- [Como converter um int em dois bytes em C/C++?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11641/101)
- [O que significa << em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53006/101)
- [Lógica dessas operações bit a bit](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/307852/101)

Esse operadores fazem só o deslocamento de bits para um lado, o que é muito simples e rápido. Seria mais ou menos você em vez de fazer todo um cálculo de divisão por 10 só usar a regrinha de tirar os dígitos da direita, bem mais rápido que fazer todas aquelas contas tradicionais de divisão, certo? Se você sabe que o divisor é uma potência de base 10 pode usar esse truque, e isso é o mesmo que o *bit shift* faz para substituir a divisão ou multiplicação (que o ganho é grande, mas não tão grande quanto a divisão) em potências de base 2. Quando o processador faz a divisão ele tem que processar de uma forma mais complicada, como fazemos quando o divisor é complicado em base 10 também.

Então, assim como se deslocar 4 dígitos em decimal você está dividindo por 10.000 (ou multiplicar se deslocar para a esquerda e preencher com zeros o adicional), quando manda deslocar 4 dígitos binários você está dividindo por 16, afinal 10 elevado a 4 dá 10.000 e 2 elevado a 4 dá 16. Portanto se a divisão fosse por 32 teria que deslocar 5 ou se fosse 8 deslocaria só 3. Se a divisão fosse por 10 por exemplo, não dá para fazer isso. Até tem como fazer duas ou mais operações que daria o mesmo resultado, e mesmo com 3 ou 4 operações deve ser mais rápido que a divisão, mas o código fica bem mais complicado, teria que comentar porque fez isso e para conseguir fazer =isso na mão dá trabalho, e pode ser que erre a mão e fique mais lento, por isso "ninguém" faz e deixam para ver se o compilador acha que vale a pena.

A otimização é justamente o compilador/JITter trocar uma instrução de processador pela outra sem você interferir. E se não for feito por conta própria você precisa fazer.

Poucas situações isso se justifica, é bom saber, mas não é que deva usar sempre. Os operadores manipuladores de bit foram criados em parte para otimização, mas o maior motivo é quando a semântica do que deseja fazer é o deslocamento de bit e não a divisão. Se o mais legível é dividir, divida.

Não pode usar essa forma em qualquer situação, a resposta do hkotsubo dá alguns detalhes sobre isso. Uma das limitações ele é não cuidar o sinal.

Por isso que eu sempre falo que para aprender precisa saber o porquê, como está querendo saber aqui. Quando você aprende uma "boa prática", ou seja, alguém fala "é assim, acredite" você não está aprendendo programar, está só decorando uma regra que não entende. Curiosidade por entender o motivo é fundamental.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

Apenas para ser pedante e esclarecer o que foi dito nos comentários, o `>>` é um operador ***bit shift*** (neste [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) é clara a separação entre operadores *bitwise* - *and* (`&`), *or* (`|`), etc - e os operadores *bit shift*).

Para ser mais preciso, a [especificação da linguagem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) (que também coloca os [operadores de *bitwise*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22) e de *shift* em seções separadas, indicando que técnica e ***pedantemente*** falando o `>>` não é um *bitwise operator* e sim um *shift operator*) chama esse operador de "*signed right shift*". E como o próprio nome diz, ele faz o deslocamento dos bits para a direita.

<sup>*Claro que se você disser que é um operador bitwise todo mundo vai entender. É só o meu pedantismo falando mais alto...*</sup>

Por exemplo, o número 38 em binário corresponde a `00100110`. Se fizermos `38 >> 4`, significa que os bits deverão ser deslocados 4 posições para a direita. Ou seja:

```
00100110  <- valor original (38)
00000010  <- deslocando 4 posições para a direita
```

Repare que os últimos 4 bits (`0110`) são perdidos com o deslocamento. E à esquerda, eles vão sendo preenchidos com zeros. O resultado é `00000010`, que equivale ao número 2 (que é o mesmo resultado de `38 / 16`).

---

E por que é equivalente? <sup><sub>(com ressalvas, veja mais sobre isso no final)</sub></sup>

Esqueça os números binários por enquanto. Imagine os números na base 10 (aqueles "normais" que todos usam no dia-a-dia).

Se eu tenho o número 457090, e quero dividir por 1000 (desconsiderando o resto da divisão e as casas decimais), basta eu eliminar os 3 últimos dígitos, resultando em 457.

Basicamente, se eu elimino apenas 1 dígito do final (45709), é o mesmo que dividir por 10. Se eu elimino 2 dígitos do final (4570) é o mesmo que dividir por 100 (ou por 10<sup>2</sup>), se eu elimino 3 dígitos do final (457) é o mesmo que dividir por 1000 (ou por 10<sup>3</sup>) e assim por diante.

De maneira geral, se eu eliminar N dígitos do final, é o mesmo que dividir o número por 10<sup>N</sup>. Mas isso só vale se o número estiver na base 10.

Generalizando essa regra, se um número está representado na base B e eu eliminar N dígitos do final, o resultado é o mesmo que dividir esse número por B<sup>N</sup>.

Então se o número estiver na base 2, e eu deslocar 4 posições para a direita (que é o mesmo que eliminar os 4 últimos dígitos), então o resultado é o mesmo que dividir esse número por 2<sup>4</sup> (ou seja, o mesmo que dividir por 16).

Se isso vai ser mais otimizado ou não, [a outra resposta já explicou em detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471634/112052) (e a resposta é basicamente: "Depende").

---

## Mas tem um porém

Isso tudo que falei só serve para números positivos. Se o número for negativo (e isso é indicado pelo primeiro bit, que em números negativos é igual a 1), aí já não é mais equivalente. Por exemplo, se o número for -38 teremos o seguinte:

```
int n = -38;
System.out.println(n / 16); // -2
System.out.println(n >> 4); // -3
```

Isso porque os bits agora são assim:

```
11111111111111111111111111011010  <- valor original (-38)
11111111111111111111111111111101  <- deslocar 4 posições para a direita (-3)
```

Ao deslocar para a direita, as posições da esquerda mantém o sinal. No caso de números positivos, o primeiro bit é zero, então ao deslocar para a direita, as posições da esquerda são preenchidas com zero. Mas em números negativos o primeiro bit é 1, e o sinal é mantido ao fazer o *right shift* (aliás, é por isso que o operador se chama "***signed** rigth shift*" - "signed" indica que é "com sinal", ou seja, o sinal é levado em conta ao se fazer o *shift*).

O resultado só dá igual se a divisão é exata (por exemplo, se fosse `-32`, ambos resultariam em `-2`).

---

Só por curiosidade, existe também um *unsigned right shift* (`>>>`), que sempre preenche as posições da esquerda com zeros. Para números positivos, vai continuar sendo equivalente à divisão, mas [para negativos dará um resultado completamente diferente](https://ideone.com/jlLUVe):

```
int n = -38;
System.out.println(n / 16); // -2
System.out.println(n >> 4); // -3
System.out.println(n >>> 4); // 268435453
```