# Como funciona teste lógico com dois números inteiros em Python?

Tags: python, operadores

Estava analisando um código e me deparei com a seguinte expressão:

```
1 & n >> k
```

Onde `n` e `k` são números inteiros.

Por ora, estou concentrado na primeira parte da expressão. Eu nunca tinha visto um teste lógico com dois números inteiros, então estou tentando entender o que esse teste significa. Eu ouvi falar que o Python interpreta 1 como `True` e qualquer outro número como `False`. Dessa forma, imaginei que esse teste seria apenas uma representação diferente de um teste do tipo `True & False`. Ocorre, porém, que `True & False` retorna `False` e, por exemplo, `1 & 3` retorna `1`.

O que significa a comparação de dois inteiros com o `&`?

Comment: isso é errado: "1 como True e qualquer outro número como False."  - o certo é que "0 é interpretado como False, e qualquer outro número como True".  Estou enfatizando por que isso é muito importante e pode se perder nas respostas mais longas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `&` não é um teste lógico, e sim uma operação feita com 2 números inteiros, cujo resultado é outro número inteiro. Para ser mais preciso, é uma [*binary bitwise operation*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).

No caso, o `&` faz o "and lógico" bit a bit: se ambos os bits são 1, o resultado é 1. Se qualquer um dos bits for zero, o resultado é zero.

Por exemplo, você citou `1 & 3`, que fica assim:

```
00000001  <-- 1 em binário
00000011  <-- 3 em binário
--------
00000001  <-- 1 & 3
```

Ou seja, quando ambos os bits são 1, o bit resultante é 1, caso contrário é zero. O resultado é o número 1.

---

No caso de `True & False`, vale lembrar que [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool), um *boolean* é uma subclasse de `int`, e `True` e `False` equivalem a 1 e 0, respectivamente.

Então `True & False` é o mesmo que `1 & 0`, que pelo que já foi explicado, resulta em zero (que [por sua vez é igual a `False`](https://ideone.com/5shTuG)):

```
00000001  <-- 1 em binário
00000000  <-- 0 em binário
--------
00000000  <-- 1 & 0
```

---

E só para completar, o `>>` é um [*shift operator*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations), que desloca os bits para a direita (tem uma explicação [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471643/112052)).

Por isso o resultado da expressão é um inteiro, não há nenhum teste lógico ou comparação sendo feito.

---

No fundo esse é um pequeno "truque" para ver se determinado bit está setado. Por exemplo, para n=13 e k=2:

```
00001101  <-- n=13

00000011  <-- n >> k (desloca 2 posições para a direita)
00000001  <-- faz o & com 1
--------
00000001  <-- resultado é 1, indicando que o bit da posição k está setado
```

Agora para n=9 e k=2:

```
00001001  <-- n=9

00000010  <-- n >> k (desloca 2 posições para a direita)
00000001  <-- faz o & com 1
--------
00000000  <-- resultado é 0, indicando que o bit da posição k não está setado
```

O `>>` é executado primeiro (seguindo a [ordem de precedência dos operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-summary)), deslocando os bits de `n` para a direita em `k` posições. Com isso o bit da posição `k` passa a ser o último (considerando, claro, que a última posição é zero, a penúltima é 1, etc).

Depois é feito o `1 & resultado do shift`, e o `&` feito com o número 1 sempre resulta em 1 se o último bit for 1, e zero em caso contrário.

Portanto a expressão indica se o bit do número `n`, da posição `k`, é 1 ou zero (considerando que o último bit é a posição zero, o penúltimo é a posição 1, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Eles são chamados de `bitwise operators`, são operações entre os números em sua forma binária. O que o `&` irá fazer, é comparar se os bits em suas casas correspondentes (verticalmente) são ambos iguais à 1.

Por exemplo:

```py
1 & 3

0 0 1   # 1 decimal em binário
0 1 1   # 3 decimal em binário
=====
0 0 1   # retorno 1 (transforma para decimal)



3 & 7

0 0 1 1   # 3 decimal em binário
0 1 1 1   # 7 decimal em binário
=======
0 0 1 1   # retorno 3 (transforma para decimal)



1 & 2

0 0 1   # 1 decimal em binário
0 1 0   # 2 decimal em binário
=====
0 0 0   # retorno 0 (transforma para decimal)
```

Comment: Acho que vale a pena um comentário sobre a frase que o A.P. "ouviu falar" - é importante entender que 0 é False, para efeitos booleanos, e qualquer outro número é equivalente a "True". - A pergunta original também usa o operador `>>`  que não foi mencionado nesta resposta.